# JS/JQuery hide element, change text, show element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to achieve the following experience:

- Slide down text to hide
- Change the text to value stored in an array (Do not change text until text is fully hidden from view)
- Slide up text to show

What keeps happening is the text is changing before the element is fully hidden. Here is the function which runs on page load...

```
var welcomeText = function() {
var welcome = ["Bienvenue.", "Willkommen.", "Benvenuto.", "Bienvenido.", "Welkom", "欢迎", "Fáilte.", "Nau mai", "Welcome."],
    title = $(".home-title"),
    counter = 0;

setInterval(function() {
    title.animate({"bottom":"-100%"},200);
    title.text(welcome[counter]);
    counter++;
    title.animate({"bottom":""},200);
    if(counter >= welcome.length) {
        counter = 0;
    }
}, 3000);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, the answer just came to me like a flash of inspiration! I had to add a time delay to the text change. here is the working solution...

```
var welcomeText = function() {
var welcome = ["Bienvenue.", "Willkommen.", "Benvenuto.", "Bienvenido.", "Welkom", "欢迎", "Fáilte.", "Nau mai", "Welcome."],
    title = $(".home-title"),
    counter = 0;

setInterval(function() {
    title.animate({"bottom":"-100%"},200);
    setTimeout(function() {
        title.text(welcome[counter]);
    }, 200);
    counter++;
    title.animate({"bottom":""},200);
    if(counter >= welcome.length) {
        counter = 0;
    }
}, 3000);}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the complete parameter for the animate function. The code inside of the function will only execute when the animate function ends.

```
title.animate({"bottom":"-100%"},200,function() {
  title.text(welcome[counter]);
  counter++;
  title.animate({"bottom":""},200);
  if(counter >= welcome.length) {
    counter = 0;
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! :)